# Mixins with state

Tags: ruby, module, state, mixins

I'm working through the "Pickaxe Book" and the author gives the following example as a technique for giving a module/mixin state without using an instance variable:

> ...the module could use a module-level hash, indexed by the current
>   object ID, to store instance-specific data...

```
module Test
  State = {}
  def state=(value)
    State[object_id] = value
  end
  def state
    State[object_id]
  end
end

class Client
  include Test
end

c1 = Client.new
c2 = Client.new
c1.state = 'cat'
c2.state = 'dog'
c1.state # => "cat"
c2.state # => "dog"
```

I am unclear on how this works exactly. In particular, `object_id`.  How is the `object_id` method able to access the `Client` instance in this manner? I tried using `length` to see if it would index according to that, but I got:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `length' for #<Client:0x00000000ecc570>
```

I'd like to make sure I understand the principles of what's going on here.

Comment: Don't use `<pre>` for code on Stack Overflow, just indent by 4 spaces. A `<pre>` does not do proper HTML escaping, so things that look like tags (e.g. `<Client:0x00000000ecc570>`) do not show up.

Comment: Oh. oops! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is the object_id method able to access the Client instance in this
>   manner?

1. The `state=()` method is inherited from the `Test` module when it is included. Included modules create an anonymous class that is inserted right above the including class in the inheritance chain.
2. This line:

   ```
   c1.state = 'cat'
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
   c1.state=('cat')
   ```

   And when `c1` calls `state=()`, inside the `state=()` method `self` will be equal to `c1`. Inside a `def`, `self` is equal to the object that called the method.
3. When you call a method with no receiver, then `self` is the implicit receiver.  Inside `state=()`:

   ```
   def state=(value)
     State[object_id] = value
   end
   ```

   the `object_id()` method is called with no receiver, so `self` becomes the receiver.  As a result, the line:

   ```
   State[object_id] = value
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
   State[self.object_id] = value
   ```

   which is equivalent to:

   ```
   State[c1.object_id] = value
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Point 3. was what was eluding me. Makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If `Client` includes `Test`, and `c1` is a `Client`, then `object_id` is `c1.object_id`, inherited from `Object`. Each Ruby object is guaranteed a unique `object_id`. Not all objects are guaranteed to have `length` (and furthermore, many objects will have non-unique length, e.g. `"f"` and `[8]` share the `length` `1`).

Comment: Sorry. I understand what `object_id` does, and how inheritance works, but I was not grasping that when `object_id` is used here, it is the same as using `self.object_id`. Is that correct? I was thinking that `object_id` was being called on `State` somehow via the `[]`. Hahaha how silly of me. That's why I tried the `length` method...because `State.methods` showed `length` as an option. I knew it wouldn't make for a good index, but i didn't know why it wouldn't work at all. Now it seems very obvious.

Comment: Yes, inside a class you can call every method without an explicit receiver (and in fact with private methods, that is the only way to call them, apart from cheating with `send`). Thus, `object_id` is same as `self.object_id`; and given that `Test` is included in `Client`, the `self` is `c1` or `c2`.